# How to explicitly trigger MasterLocustRunner.quit() in locust

Tags: locust

To simulate specific number of iterations in locust, I am using simple code flow as below :

```
class NcsoTest(TaskSet):

REQ_HEADER = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "860",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.21.0",
 }

@seq_task(1)
def user_workflow(self):

    locrunner = MasterLocustRunner()
    for i in range(1, 100, 1):
        self.send_post_request()
        self.send_get_request()
    Singleton.logger().info("Test Number reached. Stopping Locust.")
    #runners.locust_runner.quit()
    locrunner.quit()

def send_post_request(self):
    response = self.client.post("/api/v2/services", data=Singleton.json_body, headers=NcsoTest.REQ_HEADER)
    print response


def send_get_request(self):
    response = self.client.get("/api/v2/services", headers=NcsoTest.REQ_HEADER)
    print response

class NcsoLoad(HttpLocust):

    max_wait = 300
    min_wait = 300
    sleep_time = 10

    task_set = NcsoTest
```

To run this test, I am using command with below parameters :

```
--host https://10.123.123.123 --min_wait_time 300 --max_wait_time 300 --num_clients 1 --hatch_rate 1 --test_time 5m
```

Although, I am able to execute 100 requests, if these 100 request finish before 5 minutes, locust runner keeps giving error stating MasterLocustRunner needs more parameters which are locust_class & options (which I specified in locust command)

If I un-comment "runners.locust_runner.quit()" and comment "locrunner.quit()",  test keeps on waiting till the graceful terminate call from Master sent after run-time ends.

What I would like to know is, how to manually/end terminate the locust gracefully - Master and Slave.

Answer (score 0):

This has been much improved in locust 1.1. You are now be able to call `self.environment.runner.quit()` from a User (or `self.user.environment.runner.quit()` from a TaskSet)

You can also call it from a completely separate greenlet (maybe not exactly what you are looking for, but I thought I’d mention it), like here https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/extending-locust.html#run-a-background-greenlet

You should *not* create a new Runner *inside* your user tasks (which your code does). That is a little too wild :)

Comment: I called `self.environment.runner.quit()` it states `[2021-05-14 12:23:13,986] Karls-MacBook-Pro.local/INFO/locust.runners: Stopping 3 users` but the test just keeps on going in headless mode (no tasks running, they stopped, but the report keeps showing up every few seconds). I have to to ctrl+c to get out from the test. Must I call `quit()`?